# Service not stop after click

Tags: java, android, android-service, togglebutton

I've got a service that starts when i click a toggle button. It works well but when i click again the toggle i would expect the service stops but doesn't work. The service still go. This is the button(I'm using the preferences to save the state of the button):

```
check = (ToggleButton)v.findViewById(R.id.check1);
final SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean tgprefshake = preferences.getBoolean("tgprefshake", false);  //default is true
check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {                
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked){ //do this}
              Log.d("Service", "onClick: starting srvice");
              myService = new Intent(getActivity(), shakeService.class);
              //getActivity().startService(new Intent(getActivity(), shakeService.class));
              getActivity().startService(myService);                         
              SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
              editor.putBoolean("tgprefshake", true); // value to store
              editor.commit();
          } else {  
              Log.d("Service", "onClick: stopping srvice");
              //getActivity().stopService(new Intent(getActivity(), shakeService.class));
              getActivity().stopService(myService);

              SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
              editor.putBoolean("tgprefshake", false); // value to store
              editor.commit();
          }
    }
});

if (tgprefshake) //if (tgpref) may be enough, not sure
{
    check.setChecked(true);
}
else
{
    check.setChecked(false);
}
```

And the service:

```
public class shakeService extends Service implements SensorEventListener{
    // Sensors
    public SensorManager sensorManager;
    private long lastUpdate;
    public ToggleButton check ;
    public Sensor mAccelerometer;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    public void onCreate()
    {
        Log.d("", "onCreate");
        super.onCreate();   
    }
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("Service", "onDestroy");
    }
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {    
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            getWifiVibrating(event); 
        }

    }
    private void getWifiVibrating(SensorEvent event) {
        //myVib.vibrate(50);
        final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        float[] values = event.values;
        // Movement
        float x = values[0];
        float y = values[1];
        float z = values[2];

        float accelationSquareRoot = (x * x + y * y + z * z)
            / (SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH * SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH);
        long actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (accelationSquareRoot >= 3) {
          if (actualTime - lastUpdate < 600) {
            return;
          }
          lastUpdate = actualTime;
          wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
          Toast.makeText(this, "Wi-fi On", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
          .show();
    } 
}

public void onResume() {

    // register this class as a listener for the orientation and
    // accelerometer sensors
    sensorManager.registerListener(this,
    sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

public void onPause() {
    // unregister listener
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}
```

Where is the error? It shows me "Service Stopped" when i turn off the toggle but still the service still works.

Comment: You should use a ServiceConnection !

Comment: are you getting Toast saying Service Stopped?

Comment: Maybe in the onDestroy of your service you should UnregisterListener of your sensorManager ?

Comment: Just to try if it worked!! Anyway how can i solve? I mean, it starts!!! why not stops?

Comment: Why in onDestroy and not in onPause?

Comment: Does calling `super.onDestroy()` aid with this? Otherwise can you unregister the listener manually and unbind it? on Destroy will as per the docs: `The system calls this method when the service is no longer used and is being destroyed. Your service should implement this to clean up any resources such as threads, registered listeners, receivers, etc. This is the last call the service receives.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call super.onDestroy() in the end of the service's onDestroy() impementation.

Comment: i called the `super.onDestroy()` right now and also added `sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);` always in onDestroy method instead onPause and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have U think about memory leak? Every time onResume, U register the service as listener.

Comment: Do you think is better remove the onResume?

Answer (score 0):

stopService() can not stop Service right now in android. The system will stop it completely in a proper time.